# Headset mic doesn't work on orange pi 4 lts Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

- I have SoC `orange pi 4 lts` and OS `Ubuntu` on it:

```
orangepi@orangepi4-lts:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

- `orange pi 4 lts` has audio port jack 3.5
- I plugged headset with mic by `jack 3.5 4-pin` into audio port of `orange pi 4 lts`
- Headset as speaker works fine
- **But mic of headset doesn't work**
- By the way, native mic on board of `orange pi 4 lts` works also fine
- Audio sources list here:

```
orangepi@orangepi4-lts:~$ pacmd list-sources
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.platform-heaadphones-sound.stereo-fallback.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 54262 /  83% / -4.92 dB,   front-right: 54262 /  83% / -4.92 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 6 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 1 <alsa_card.platform-heaadphones-sound>
    module: 8
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "rockchip-es8316c"
        alsa.long_card_name = "rockchip-es8316c"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_simple_card"
        device.bus_path = "platform-heaadphones-sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/heaadphones-sound/sound/card0"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.platform-heaadphones-sound.stereo-fallback>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9000
    volume: front-left: 38611 /  59% / -13.79 dB,   front-right: 38611 /  59% / -13.79 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 2.71 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.platform-heaadphones-sound>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ff880000.i2s-ES8316 HiFi ES8316 HiFi-0"
        alsa.id = "ff880000.i2s-ES8316 HiFi ES8316 HiFi-0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "rockchip-es8316c"
        alsa.long_card_name = "rockchip-es8316c"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_simple_card"
        device.bus_path = "platform-heaadphones-sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/heaadphones-sound/sound/card0"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hw:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "stereo-fallback"
        device.profile.description = "Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    ports:
        analog-input: Analog Input (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    active port: <analog-input>
```

- `pulseaudio` version

```
orangepi@orangepi4-lts:~$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 15.99.1
```

- `ALSA` version:

```
orangepi@orangepi4-lts:~$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.18.5-rk3399.
```

Dear friends, I'm not familiar with `ALSA` and `pulseaudio` and appreciate any help :)
How to fix the mic of headset and use it as record device?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I fixed the problem of headphone mic by:

```
amixer cset name='Differential Mux' lin1-rin1
amixer cset name="ADC Capture Volume" 192
```

I found these steps in manual guide of `orange pi 4 lts` here:
https://uelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/OrangePi_4_LTS_User-manual_v2.1.pdf

now I can record via headphone mic by:

```
arecord -d 5 -f cd test-mic.wav
```